# Append new element after element clicked with html template

Tags: angularjs

I have an `ng-click` function that successfully appends a new `<tr>` to the one that was clicked

```
function expandTransactionDetail($event) {
    var row = angular.element($event.currentTarget);
    row.after('<tr><td>Holla!</td></tr>');
}
```

This HTML is currently just a test. The HTML will become more complex. I would like to derive the HTML from a template file. Do I need to make use of the `$compile` feature in AngularJS? `ngInclude`?

Comment: Is it possible for you to create some model that will represent your rows, and use `ng-repeat`? In this way clicks will modify that model (using splice) instead of manipulating the DOM, and the solution will be much clearer.

Comment: unfortunately no, The initial call to the database will only retrieve the parent record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Don Juwe recommended I created my own directive for the HTML

```
function expandTransactionDetail($event) {
    var row = angular.element($event.currentTarget);
    var detailRow = $compile('<div secr-transactions-listing-detail>')(scope);
    row.after(detailRow);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you really really want is to create a [**directive**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) in which you can have your own *template*, *scope* and more fun stuff:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '=myData'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.on('click', function() {
                elem.append(scope.data);
            });
        }
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <my-directive my-data="'Well done!'">Click me to append String!</my-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: that pointed me in the right direction. I needed to append a directive inside an ng-repeat of another directive